# Asterisk + asterisk-java listen new channels

Tags: java, events, asterisk, channel

Asterisk 11.4.0
Asterisk-java: 1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT

I've try to run this code:

```
import org.asteriskjava.live.AsteriskChannel;
import org.asteriskjava.live.AsteriskQueue;
import org.asteriskjava.live.AsteriskQueueEntry;
import org.asteriskjava.live.internal.AsteriskAgentImpl;
import org.asteriskjava.live.AsteriskServer;
import org.asteriskjava.live.AsteriskServerListener;
import org.asteriskjava.live.DefaultAsteriskServer;
import org.asteriskjava.live.ManagerCommunicationException;
import org.asteriskjava.live.MeetMeRoom;
import org.asteriskjava.live.MeetMeUser;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;

public class HelloLiveEverything implements AsteriskServerListener, PropertyChangeListener
{
private AsteriskServer asteriskServer;

public HelloLiveEverything()
{
    asteriskServer = new DefaultAsteriskServer("localhost", "manager", "password");
}

public void run() throws ManagerCommunicationException
{
    // listen for new events
    asteriskServer.addAsteriskServerListener(this);
    // add property change listeners to existing objects
    for (AsteriskChannel asteriskChannel : asteriskServer.getChannels())
    {
        System.out.println(asteriskChannel);
        asteriskChannel.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }
}

public void onNewAsteriskChannel(AsteriskChannel channel)
{
    System.out.println(channel);
    channel.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
}

public void onNewMeetMeUser(MeetMeUser user)
{
    System.out.println(user);
    user.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
}


    public void onNewQueueEntry(AsteriskQueueEntry user)
{
    System.out.println(user);
    user.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
}

    public void onNewAgent(AsteriskAgentImpl user)
{
    System.out.println(user);
    user.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
}


public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent)
{
    System.out.println(propertyChangeEvent);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    HelloLiveEverything helloLiveEverything = new HelloLiveEverything();
    helloLiveEverything.run();
    while (true) {
}

}
}
```

When executed, connectios is OK. This code show me current channels but never show me new channels when callers make a calls.
I need to catch the events when new asterisk channels are opening.
What I made wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try This:
Your Class `HelloLiveEverything` should implement `ManagerEventListener`
 
then override the `onManagerEvent` method

```
@Override
 public void onManagerEvent(ManagerEvent event) {
        String event_name = event.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (event_name.equals("DialEvent")) {
        DialEvent e = (DialEvent) event;
        System.out.println(e.getCallerIdNum());//caller number
        System.out.println(e.getDestination());//Called number
//do something here
}
    }
```

edit asterisk manager.conf :
`[manager]
secret = password
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0

permit=209.16.236.73/255.255.255.0; change this ip with one your java app is using permit=127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0 
read = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,originate; add full permission 
write = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,originate; add full permission`

Comment: Added ManagerEventListener in implemets, add necessary imports and override onManagerEvent
The same. Current channels are shown, no any new channel.

Comment: it is already set permit to all and all read/write permissions

Comment: I use 1.0.0-CI latest snapshot

Comment: can you remove If condition " if (event_name.equals("DialEvent"))" and print out any event you receive "System.out.println(event_name)"

Comment: Add it... but no any response. Silence in output.

Comment: I think you need to capture some network traffic  using wireshark and see if asterisk is sending any events at all . you can add wireshark filter : tcp.port=5038 and then from analyze menu select follow tcp stream and you should see events in a readable format . if you didnot find any events I think you need  to test your code on  a lower version of asterisk say v8

Comment: I've change this code only for implements ManagerEventListener and made this
`@Override
    public void onManagerEvent(ManagerEvent event)
    {
        // just print received events
        System.out.println("GOT EVENT:"+event);
    }
`
This code shows me only 
org.asteriskjava.manager.event.RegistryEvent, org.asteriskjava.manager.event.PeerStatusEvent

Comment: After read=all, write=all in manager.conf and restart *, not only manager reload in CLI, I can see all events
Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi @Vlad i am getting CDR event in onManagerEvent but when i am trying to save this event object into database then exception occurring. Can you suggest some way how can i save CDR records in database within java/Hibernate etc. Thanks in advance